# No serial data from Adafruit GPS (on Arduino 101)

Tags: gps

New [Adafruit GPS](https://www.adafruit.com/product/746) connected to my Arduino 101 board.

When trying to use the RX/TX hardware serial (on digital pins 0 / 1), with a simple sketch (described by Adafruit) to output a serial response, I'm not seing anything in the serial monitor (9600 baud).

```arduino
// this sketch will allow you to bypass the Atmega chip
// and connect the Ultimate GPS directly to the USB/Serial
// chip converter.

// Connect VIN to +5V
// Connect GND to Ground
// Connect GPS RX (data into GPS) to Digital 0
// Connect GPS TX (data out from GPS) to Digital 1

void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

Wires connected as in the sketch, also tried swapping them out in case of faulty wire.

Went on to try TinyGPS++ default example code, across a variety of pins: 3,4 & 8,9 & 0,1.

```arduino
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx). EDITED BELOW.
*/

static const int RXPin = 8, TXPin = 9;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("FullExample.ino"));
  Serial.println(F("An extensive example of many interesting TinyGPS++ features"));
  Serial.print(F("Testing TinyGPS++ library v. ")); Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
  Serial.println(F("by Mikal Hart"));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Sats HDOP Latitude   Longitude   Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum"));
  Serial.println(F("          (deg)      (deg)       Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail"));
  Serial.println(F("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
}

void loop()
{
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  printInt(gps.satellites.value(), gps.satellites.isValid(), 5);
  printInt(gps.hdop.value(), gps.hdop.isValid(), 5);
  printFloat(gps.location.lat(), gps.location.isValid(), 11, 6);
  printFloat(gps.location.lng(), gps.location.isValid(), 12, 6);
  printInt(gps.location.age(), gps.location.isValid(), 5);
  printDateTime(gps.date, gps.time);
  printFloat(gps.altitude.meters(), gps.altitude.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.course.deg(), gps.course.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.speed.kmph(), gps.speed.isValid(), 6, 2);
  printStr(gps.course.isValid() ? TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(gps.course.value()) : "*** ", 6);

  unsigned long distanceKmToLondon =
    (unsigned long)TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON) / 1000;
  printInt(distanceKmToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 9);

  double courseToLondon =
    TinyGPSPlus::courseTo(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON);

  printFloat(courseToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 7, 2);

  const char *cardinalToLondon = TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(courseToLondon);

  printStr(gps.location.isValid() ? cardinalToLondon : "*** ", 6);

  printInt(gps.charsProcessed(), true, 6);
  printInt(gps.sentencesWithFix(), true, 10);
  printInt(gps.failedChecksum(), true, 9);
  Serial.println();

  smartDelay(1000);

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
    Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
}

// This custom version of delay() ensures that the gps object
// is being "fed".
static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void printFloat(float val, bool valid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (!valid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printInt(unsigned long val, bool valid, int len)
{
  char sz[32] = "*****************";
  if (valid)
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printDateTime(TinyGPSDate &d, TinyGPSTime &t)
{
  if (!d.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("********** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d ", d.month(), d.day(), d.year());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }

  if (!t.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("******** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }

  printInt(d.age(), d.isValid(), 5);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printStr(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartDelay(0);
}
```

Serial is spitting out this for every update:

> No GPS data received: check wiring

GPS is on, and can see based on the fix LED that satellite fix has occurred in both tests – no difference in output. Wires checked.

Maybe suboptimal pin solder job, but can't see that it should give no signal?

[image: Solder job]

EDIT: After suggestions, re-soldered pinheader – still nothing in the serial prompt on hardware serial (pin 0,1), software serial (pin 3,4) and TinyGPS++ throws the same error (pin 3-4 + 8-9). Double-checked RX/TX order.

A colleague found an old [Ublox Neo 6-M GPS](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/neo-6-series), I plugged it in and repeated the above with the same empty serial results, not sure what to make of this..

[image]

Comment: Solder looks sort of okay, though you may have issue on the Tx pin (middle) where there is no verified solder wicking into the barrel like the others. 

As for the code, it looks like the error is caused by the `smartDelay()` function where it is listening for data from the Tx line and gives you that warning if it does not see more than ten characters after five seconds of waiting for data.

Maybe try temporarily printing raw data via `ss.read()` in your loop rather than relying on the gps library, to verify if the module is transmitting any data on the Tx pin in the first place.

Comment: @depwl9992 I agree the TX pin may need a bit more solder.  You can also use the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE to look for the raw data output (without writing or modifying any code).  This way you can tell if the problem is with the code or the wiring... its easy to get TX/RX swapped and I've done it before!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, no luck though, edited post

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally fixed it when booting up the board tonight – not sure what changed but the serial prompt is on fire.

Wires: 5V - VIN, GND – GND, TX – 8, RX – 9

**Code:**

```arduino
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// setup gps serial
int gpsTxPin = 8;
int gpsRxPin = 9;
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(gpsTxPin, gpsRxPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //set monitor to 9600

  gpsSerial.begin(9600); //adjust for GPS unit

  Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop()
{
  while(gpsSerial.available())
  {
    char c = gpsSerial.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

**Excerpt from serial monitor:**

```
...

$GPVTG,248.75,T,,M,0.19,N,0.35,K,A*3F
$GPGGA,231351.000,,,,,0,05,,,M,,M,,*7A
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GPGSV,2,1,07,13,65,290,32,30,54,066,36,20,48,286,33,15,31,288,31*75

...
```